# Using MongoDB's bsondump command in windows

Tags: mongodb

I am a newbie to MongoDB. I have several bson files that I would like to convert to JSON for further processing in Python. I have installed MongoDB on Windows 7 (64 bit). Basic commands of mongodb works fine. But the following bsondump command issues the following error. Please advice.

bsondump Federer.bson> Federer.json
2014-06-02T14:08:24.490-0400 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Federer.bson file is placed in mongodb/bin folder.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at pymongo http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/ if you want to use mongodb with python. For your trouble, how did you generate your bson file ?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this (Win 7 64 bit) as follows:

First, created a test Federer collection:

```
C:\Users\Adam\mongo\2.6.1\bin>
C:\Users\Adam\mongo\2.6.1\bin>mongo.exe
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.1
connecting to: test
> for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){db.Federer.insert({a : i});}
```

Next, dump out the records to BSON:

```
C:\Users\Adam\mongo\2.6.1\bin>mongodump.exe -d test -c Federer
connected to: 127.0.0.1
2014-06-02T21:01:34.831+0100 DATABASE: test      to     dump\test
2014-06-02T21:01:34.832+0100    test.Federer to dump\test\Federer.bson
2014-06-02T21:01:34.833+0100             10 documents
2014-06-02T21:01:34.836+0100    Metadata for test.Federer to dump\test\Federer.metadata.json
```

Now, let's move Federer.bson into the bin folder and complete the test:

```
C:\Users\Adam\mongo\2.6.1\bin>bsondump Federer.bson > Federer.json
10 objects found
```

Finally, the contents of Federer.json:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "538cd7d9154f90334fb94510" ), "a" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "538cd7d9154f90334fb94511" ), "a" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "538cd7d9154f90334fb94512" ), "a" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "538cd7d9154f90334fb94513" ), "a" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "538cd7d9154f90334fb94514" ), "a" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "538cd7d9154f90334fb94515" ), "a" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "538cd7d9154f90334fb94516" ), "a" : 6 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "538cd7d9154f90334fb94517" ), "a" : 7 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "538cd7d9154f90334fb94518" ), "a" : 8 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "538cd7d9154f90334fb94519" ), "a" : 9 }
```

So, I am not sure what the issue is on your system - perhaps the input BSON file is not the correct format.